# Is there a way to solve error of pentaho unable to open a pprt file?

Tags: mysql, linux, xml, reporting-services, pentaho

I am attempting to open a `.pprt` file with Pentaho report designer but it keeps returning the error of `unable to open the file as valid report definition`. I also went far to extract the file locally (I use a Linux Ubuntu) then tried to open the different `.XML` files but is of no use if I can get my specific MySQL queries. I'd appreciate some help on how to attack this error.

Find the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: Pentaho report designer suppose to open report with extension (*.prpt) not .pprt. Anyways, I guess you were generating report from any newer version of report designer but now you are trying to open same report in older version or vice-versa.

Comment: Oh wow, that makes sense. Let me check that out, thanks.

Comment: Did your problem solved?